# How to use OAUTH to login user using 500PX API

Tags: iphone, oauth

I am trying to login users via the 500 PX API,

http://developers.500px.com/docs/oauth-request

It seems like the only way to do this is via a webview, have the user authenticate, and once they login to 500px, they will be rerouted back to my app with the access token.

How can I do this without a web view? I want ti implement 2 text fields, one for username and one for password, and then login the user.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole premise behind the OAuth pattern is that 3rd party developers should never be trusted with the user's username and password. Instead they are redirected to the service's login portal, which the user knows and trusts, where they enter in their username and password, give permission to the untrusted third party application, and then are redirected back to the untrusted application with an authorization key and secret, which the third party application can then use to access the service on the user's behalf.

User's are used to this pattern, they trust it. By breaking this pattern you are breaking convention and web savvy users are less likely to use your application.